# How to re import the java module in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Somehow I lose my java module on Android side.

[image]

I see my node_nodule/ still have them

How do I get them back on Android side ?

Comment: Did you try to link the module again?

Comment: Yes, I have try react-native link it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try to change your file hierarchy to `Packages`?

Comment: I don't. I just yarn add other library. But I fix the issue just by closing everything and re open Android Studio. It looks like some conflict between Visual Studio Code and Android Studio.